# Formatting Partitions for fresh install

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

my son set my computer up, and (from what I can make out), he installed Windows itself on the C Drive, and then partitioned the remaining 900GB (it's a 1TB HD) for my files, music, etc.

I believe he set it up with the idea that any programs and Windows components are installed to the C drive, keeping it all seperate. The issue is, he's away travelling now, and I can't contact him for a couple of weeks!

I'd like to install a fresh Operating System, and don't particularly enjoy this multi-drive setup. Is there a simple way to make everything one partition again, and re-install Windows from scratch?

I've tried to find as much as I can on my own, but I'm a little uneducated tech-wise, so would apprecaite any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is simple if you know how. ;)

On a serious note, you didn't mention which version of Windows you're installing.  But if it's 7 or later, the installation process itself will let you set up partitioning.  After you back up your data, just boot from the Windows DVD and run through the setup process.  When you get to the point where you have a choice between "Upgrade" and "Custom", choose "Custom" (the lower of the two options). Then it will ask where you want to install Windows.  You can delete the existing partitions, and when you have deleted everything, it should only say Drive 0 Partition 1.  Choose that for the installation location.  It will automatically create a 100 MB boot partition, but that's OK.

As I mentioned,  **make sure you back up all of your important data before you start**.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! Yes, I should have mentioned it's Windows 10 Pro. I am thinking, however, of moving onto a Linux OS - but your guidence is exactly what I needed, so thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want the original installation medium or want to make a new one if you are able, for example download the media creation tool from Microsoft to make a Windows 8.1 or 10 dvd or usb. This can be done from your current system.

Then during the installation, you can remove all existing partitions and/or reconfigure the ones you'd like to change. Warning: removing partitions generally removes all files. Resizing is possible, but requires some more skills (and potentially linux). Reading your questions suggest simply removing everything and reinstalling Windows as one partition would be enough.

Here is an informational source that might help guide you further to successfully (re)install Windows 10. https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1950-clean-install-windows-10-a.html

Windows 10 is still free for people who claim to use one or more of the accessibility tools. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/accessibility/windows10upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't change this setup. This is made exactly as I've always installed Windows. The advantage being you can re-install a 100% clean (formatting the disk etc) Windows operating system later (on volume C:) without affecting any of your personal files which are instead on volume D:.

All personal folders like `My Documents`, `My Pictures` etc (which are just shortcuts to some folders), you can edit to point to a folder in the D: partition, if you are used to put files at these locations. So the user experience should be quite the same.

Of course you need to take a little care before doing a reinstall to check that you haven't left any documents at volume C:. And always make a backup, but you will not need to use it unless a very unlikely drive failure during install, or if you accidentally reinstall on D: instead of C:.

I guess he did this for the whole process to be much safer and quicker the next time around. You don't have to search through volume C: like a detective to find all personal files, if you have adapted the habit of knowingly storing all important documents on drive D:.

Just let C: be called `Local Disk`, and rename D: to `DATA` or `MYFILES` or something of your liking.

This is especially an advantage if you have sub-critical data you don't back up. Like pictures, videos etc, that take a lot of space, but you may not have space to make a backup. I always reinstall without backing up a lot of sub-critical data, and having two partitions or more makes this just much easier.